# Ionic / ReactJS - Vertical centering with Flex not working on Ionic

Tags: html, css, reactjs, ionic-framework, ionic5

On this `Ionic` / `ReactJS` project you can try by yourself on `Stackblitz`:

https://stackblitz.com/edit/ionic-react-routing-ctdywr?file=src%2Fpages%2FGreetings.tsx

I have the follwing code:

```
import React from 'react';
import { IonButton, IonContent, IonPage } from '@ionic/react';

const Greetings = () => {
  return (
    <IonPage className="loginPage">
      <IonContent fullscreen>
        <div
          className="container"
          style={{
            display: 'flex',
            flexDirection: 'column',
            justifyContent: 'center',
            alignItems: 'center',
          }}
        >
          <IonButton>Say Hello</IonButton>
          <IonButton>Say World</IonButton>
        </div>
      </IonContent>
    </IonPage>
  );
};

export default Greetings;
```

which renders the following DOM content and CSS:

[image]

**My problelm is:** I was expecting that the buttons inside were vertically and horizontally aligned, however I get what you can see on the image below:

[image]

where you can see that the buttons are aligned to the top.

Any idea on how to solve this issue?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A well-asked question with a simple answer.

[You are missing IonRow and height 100% as shown in this fork.](https://stackblitz.com/edit/ionic-react-routing-5foajg?file=src%2Fpages%2FGreetings.tsx)

```
<IonPage className="loginPage">
      <IonContent fullscreen>
        <IonRow
          className="container"
          style={{
            height: '100%',
            display: 'flex',
            flexDirection: 'column',
            justifyContent: 'center',
            alignItems: 'center',
          }}
        >
          <IonButton>Say Hello</IonButton>
          <IonButton>Say World</IonButton>
        </IonRow>
      </IonContent>
    </IonPage>
```